# Get part of np array with parameters

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I am using python and numpy. I am using n dimensional array.
I want to select all elements with index like

```
arr[a,b,:,c]
```

but I want to be able to select slice position like parameter. For example if the parameter

```
#pos =2
arr[a,b,:,c]

#pos =1
arr[a,:,b,c]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would move the axis of interest (at pos) to the front with `numpy.moveaxis(array,pos,0)`[[1](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)] and then simply slice with `[:,a,b,c]`.

There is also `numpy.take`[[2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html)], but in your case you would still need to loop over each dimension a,b,c, so I think moveaxis is more convenient. Maybe there is an even more direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of moving the slicing axis to one end is a good one.  Various numpy functions use that idea.

```
In [171]: arr = np.ones((2,3,4,5),int)
In [172]: arr[0,0,:,0].shape
Out[172]: (4,)
In [173]: arr[0,:,0,0].shape
Out[173]: (3,)
```

Another idea is to build a indexing tuple:

```
In [176]: idx = (0,0,slice(None),0)
In [177]: arr[idx].shape
Out[177]: (4,)
In [178]: idx = (0,slice(None),0,0)
In [179]: arr[idx].shape
Out[179]: (3,)
```

To do this programmatically it may be easier to start with a list or array that can be modified, and then convert it to a tuple for indexing.  Details will vary depending on how you prefer to specify the axis and variables.

If any of `a,b,c` are arrays (or lists), you may get some shape surprises, since it's a case of mixing advanced and basic indexing.  But as long as they are scalars, that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array `arr` based on your preferences before you try to slice it, since you move your axis of interest (i.e. the `:`) "to the back". This way, you can rearrange `arr`, s.t. you can always call `arr[a,b,c]`.
Example with only `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np

a = 0
b = 2
target_axis = 1

# Generate some random data
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=[3, 3, 3], dtype=int)
print(arr)
#[[[0 8 2]
#  [3 9 4]
#  [0 3 6]]
#
# [[8 5 4]
#  [9 8 5]
#  [8 6 1]]
#
# [[2 2 5]
#  [5 3 3]
#  [9 1 8]]]

# Define transpose s.t. target_axis is the last axis
transposed_shape = np.arange(arr.ndim)
transposed_shape = np.delete(transposed_shape, target_axis)
transposed_shape = np.append(transposed_shape, target_axis)
print(transposed_shape)
#[0 2 1] 
# Caution! These 0 and 2 above do not come from a or b.
# Instead they are the indices of the axes.

# Transpose arr
arr_T = np.transpose(arr, transposed_shape)
print(arr_T)
#[[[0 3 0]
#  [8 9 3]
#  [2 4 6]]
#
# [[8 9 8]
#  [5 8 6]
#  [4 5 1]]
#
# [[2 5 9]
#  [2 3 1]
#  [5 3 8]]]

print(arr_T[a,b])
#[2 4 6]
```